# sencha touch change colour of a specific list item

Tags: javascript, list, sencha-touch

have a very basic list component, but want to change the row colour of some rows depending on a value/ I have tried setting a tpl but it doesnt seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

```
Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', {
    id : 'mylist',
    store: myStore,
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
             '<tpl for=".">'
             '    <tpl if="val == 0"><div style="background-color:red">{name}</div></tpl>',
             '    <tpl if="val == 1"><div>{name}</div></tpl>',
             '</tpl>'
    )
});
```

Comment: Your code should work, I think, if your data looks like this: `[{val: 1, name: 'name1'}...]`

Answer (score 3):

Ah, basic mistake, this is what you've got in your code ::

```
<tpl if="val == 0">
```

And this is what it should be instead :::

```
<tpl if="val === 0">
```

** Notice the three "equal to" signs that you need to add between the two values you're actually comparing. So if you normally wrote

```
x=y
```

Then in a template that would be

```
x==y  // (you basically add an extra equal)
```

So a conditional statement like

```
x==y  //when you're checking if the values are equal
```

Becomes

```
x===y
```

EDIT :: Adding the Coding for the entire row to be filled with the background color assigned

NOTE :: Please make a separate XTemplate object, and not inline tpl code. That will allow you to harness the full potential of the XTemplate, including member functions which are incredibly cool !

**Trial 1 ::**

*tpl Code to be added for background color*

```
  '<li class="{[this.listClasses(xindex,xcount)]}">',
          '<b>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; {nameOfMeeting}</b>',
          '<br>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Start Time : {start} &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  ||  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  End Time : {end}',
  '</li>',
   {
        listClasses : function(position, size){
            var classes = [];
            if (position%2===0) {classes.push("even")}
            else                {classes.push("odd")};
            if (position === 1) {classes.push("first")}
            else                {classes.push("last")};
            return classes.join(" ");
        }
    }
```

//Note : I've added in the helper functions that I'm using to change the background color of the class. My tpl, basically uses alternate color on every list line. So if the first line is green, the second is yellow, the third is green, the fourth is yellow, and so on.

*Associated CSS to be added (for the listClasses selected in the li tag)*

```
#meetingsList li.odd { background-color: #ebdde2; }
#meetingsList li.even { background-color: #fdeef4; }
#meetingsList li.odd { border-bottom: 1px solid #999; }
#meetingsList li.even { border-bottom-style: none; }
```

**EDIT Trial 2 :: New CSS to be added**

CSS

```
.testview .x-dataview-item {            border-bottom : 1px solid #cccbcb;        }        
.testview .x-item-selected {           background-color: #006bb6;           background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #50b7ff), color-stop(2%, #0080da), color-stop(100%, #005692) );            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#50b7ff, #0080da 2%, #005692);            
background-image: linear-gradient(#50b7ff, #0080da 2%, #005692);            
color: #fff;;            
text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0 -0.08em 0;            
border-color: #103656;        }
```

To add the CSS into Code, add the following to the list object ::

```
{
 xtype : 'list'
 . . . . 
 cls : 'testview'
}
```

Comment: the problem is that only the middle area is coloured, not the complete row - see the other comment...

Comment: @swalkner: I have added in the background color part of the answer. Can you try the code above ?

Comment: it doesn't colour the entire cell as well, unfortunately... see https://dl.dropbox.com/u/119600/senchatouch.png

Comment: @swalkner : I added a "Trial 2" into the code above. It seems to be working on my side. Can you give it a try ? If it works, I'll remove the non-working code

Comment: that doesn't work at all, unfortunately :/ I've got the code on github, do you see any errors? https://github.com/haemi/CrossfitSencha/blob/master/app/view/AnmeldungenListView.js and https://github.com/haemi/CrossfitSencha/blob/master/resources/sass/app.scss thanks!

Comment: Umm.. you've put a padding value of 10px on all four sides of the div, and a border radius !! Dude !! Obviously it won't work then

Comment: yeah - I did that only because it didn't work with the CSS provided; removing padding and border radius on my div didn't change anything. But I just found out the solution: set padding on `.x-list-item-body` to 0px! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This may be late but you can do it this way

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'list',
    id: 'patientList',
    store: app.stores.patientList,
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl if="overDue14Days &gt; 0"><div class="severeItem"></div></tpl><tpl if="overDue3Days &gt; 0"><div class="mildItem"></div></tpl>', '<div class="listBox">', '<div class="listText">{patientFirstName} {patientLastName}', '<div class="metadata">{numberOfOrders} orders</div>', '</div>', '<div class="listSpacer"></div>', '<div class="deleteItem" id="notMyPatientButton"></div>', '<div class="listArrow"></div>', '</div>'),
```

and in your css file just add the list style

```
.patientList.x-list-item
{
    background-color: #ff0000;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'list',
    id: 'patientList',
    store: app.stores.patientList,
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl if="overDue14Days &gt; 0"><div class="severeItem"></div></tpl><tpl if="overDue3Days &gt; 0"><div class="mildItem"></div></tpl>', '<div class="listBox">', '<div class="listText">{patientFirstName} {patientLastName}', '<div class="metadata">{numberOfOrders} orders</div>', '</div>', '<div class="listSpacer"></div>', '<div class="deleteItem" id="notMyPatientButton"></div>', '<div class="listArrow"></div>', '</div>'),
```

In my css instead of a background color I use a background gradient:

```
    .severeItem {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0%,#fccdce), color-stop(10%, #fcc2c4), color-stop(50%,#fdaaac), color-stop(100%, #ff8891));
}

    .mildItem{ 
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(0%,#feedba), color-stop(10%, #fcda8b), color-stop(50%,#fdd986), color-stop(100%, #ffe888));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the example! Will this colour the entire list row? I tried something similar and it only coloured the middle area (the div containing the text)

Comment: stan229 - how did you achieve that? When I do it this way, I've got the same result as @neolaser - only the middle area is coloured

Comment: @neolaser :: Please select the answer that matches your query and upvote it to close this thread.

Comment: @SashaZd : why? the problem isn't solved yet, if I understand correctly - not the entire row is coloured...

Comment: As I understand the entire row is not coloured as of yet. Hopefully someone can find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create your own styles and override sencha touch list-item css

```
.myList {

  }
.myList .x-list-item {
    position:relative;
    color:#333;
    padding:0em 0em;
    min-height:2.1em;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:box;
    border-top:1px solid #c8c8c8

}
.myList .x-list-item .brands-row-spon {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    padding:0.5em 0.8em;
    min-height:2.6em;
}
.myList .x-list-item .brands-row {
    width: 100%;
    min-height:2.6em;
    padding:0.5em 0.8em;
}
```

> 1. Add cls property of sencha touch list item

```
new Ext.List({
        fullscreen: true,
        id:'xList',
        itemTpl :xListTpl,
        cls:'myList',
        grouped :true,
        store:  new Ext.data.Store({
        model:'yourModel'
        })
       })
```

> 1. Add a condition to change the colour of a specific list item in your list itemTpl

```
  var  xListTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
                                '<tpl for=".">',
                                '<tpl if="isSponsored ==&quot;true&quot;"">',
                                '<div class="brands-row-spon">',
                                '</tpl>',
                                '<tpl if="isSponsored !=&quot;true&quot;"">',
                                '<div  class="brands-row">',
                                '</tpl>',
'</tpl>'
                                );
```